# 'Figure' in tikz makes image move 'forward'

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I have a weird problem, whereby if I make my existing tikz picture a 'figure', it suddenly moves forward, as in, past the paragraph that comes after it in the code.

That is, if the code that makes the figure comes before a paragraph in my editor, then when compiled and viewed as a PDF, the figure jumps forward, past the paragraph. I do not know what is happening, or how to fix it.

My code is:

```
The cow jumped over the moon as shown in this figure:

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw the axes
    \draw [->,black] (\var*-1.5,0) -- (\var*3,0) ;
    \draw [->,black] (0,\var*-1.5) -- (0,\var*3) ;    
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Foo axis caption} \label{fig:M1} 
\end{figure}

As can be seen in the anove figure, the cow jumped over the moon
```

Now, all those problems started when I added the:

```
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
```

and

```
 \caption{Foo axis caption} \label{fig:M1} 
 \end{figure}
```

Prior to that, I didnt have a problem, but at the same time, I didnt have a figure where I could add a caption.

Appreciate any insights, thanks.

EDIT:

Here is the figure I am trying to center its caption for:

[image]

Further more, here are all the packaged I am using:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xspace}
```

Comment: `figure` is a floating environment: Its main function is to allow LaTeX to move the figure to optimise page breaks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess I can live with that.... is there a way to make the caption be truly centered though? Right now it seems to be visually too much to the left...

Comment: It should be centred, please always post complete (small) document showing all packages used. Impossible to say just from a fragment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, please see my edits. I put up a screen shot of the off-centered caption

Comment: As I said without seeing a complete small (source) document that shows the effect it is impossible to say. You have something defining a flush left caption style but impossible to guess what that is.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited my post to include all the packages I am using.

Comment: sorry it doesn't help in particular it doesnt show the class file and in general it _always_  [helps to post a complete document that shows the problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)  (but someone else can take over: bed time in this part of the world:)

Comment: Very bad title. There is no "figure" environment in Tikz, this environment is in LaTeX, and perhaps it customized by a special class or a special package. It's more interesting to give us the class that you used or a complete example. The tikz environment creates a box only a box like a lot of others packages. Then you used "figure" to place this box in your document, but the options of "figure" are not a part of Tikz.

Comment: @AlainMatthes I am a LaTeX/Tikz noob so please bear with me the muddled up concepts as I learn what is what. That said, feel free to edit the title to make it clearer. The class is the IEEE Transaction Class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David said in a comment, your figure moves because you are using the floating environment `figure` whose function is to allow LaTeX to move the figure to optimize page breaks.

Regrading the caption position, seeing the style of the caption in the image, my guess is you are using the `IEEEtran` document class; in this class, captions are flushleft, but the `conference` class option can give you centered captions:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}% just for the example
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,intersections}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{figure}
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize}]

    % Draw the axes
    \draw [->,black] (-1.5,0) -- (3,0) ;
    \draw [->,black] (0,-1.5) -- (0,3) ;

    % Draw the line
    \path[name path=line,draw,-] (0,0) -- (3,2);

    % Draw the circle
    \path [name path=greencircle,draw,green] (+1.5,0) circle (1.5);
    \path [name path=bluecircle,draw,cyan] (0,1.5) circle (1.5);

% find intersections of line and circles
\path[name intersections={of=line and bluecircle, by={a,b}}];
\path[name intersections={of=line and greencircle, by={c,d}}];

% lines from axes to intersection points
    \draw[dashed,cyan] (0,0|-b) -- (b);
    \draw[dashed,cyan] (b|-0,0) -- (b);
    \draw[dashed,green] (0,0|-c) -- (c);
    \draw[dashed,green] (c|-0,0) -- (c);;
  %  \node[] at (-0.25,1.78){$y$};

     \node[left] at (0,0|-b) {$y_3$};
     \node[below] at (b|-0,0) {$x_3$};

     \node[left] at (0,0|-c) {$y_2$};
     \node[below] at (c|-0,0) {$x_2$};  

   \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
% draw braces
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=0.5pt,mirror},yshift=0pt] (O) -- (b) node [midway,yshift=-9pt, xshift =6pt]{$|z_3|$};
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=0.5pt},yshift=0pt] (O) -- (c) node [midway,yshift=11pt, xshift =-5pt]{$|z_2|$};

   % \node[] at (2.9,-0.25) {$x$};

    % Draw the angle
    \draw [red] (0,0.3) arc (90:33:0.3);
    \draw[red] (0,0.4)arc(90:33:0.4);
    \node[] at (60:.6)  {$\alpha$};

    % Done
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Differential Beamformer Patterns}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the figure to appear exactly where you wrote it in the code, don't use a floating environment such as `figure`. Instead, you can use a `minipage`  and the `\captionof` command from the `capt-of` package to provide the caption; a little example (I added some spacing using `\medskip`; you could also use `\bigskip` for more spacing):

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}% just for the example
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,intersections}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]\par\medskip
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize}]

    % Draw the axes
    \draw [->,black] (-1.5,0) -- (3,0) ;
    \draw [->,black] (0,-1.5) -- (0,3) ;

    % Draw the line
    \path[name path=line,draw,-] (0,0) -- (3,2);

    % Draw the circle
    \path [name path=greencircle,draw,green] (+1.5,0) circle (1.5);
    \path [name path=bluecircle,draw,cyan] (0,1.5) circle (1.5);

% find intersections of line and circles
\path[name intersections={of=line and bluecircle, by={a,b}}];
\path[name intersections={of=line and greencircle, by={c,d}}];

% lines from axes to intersection points
    \draw[dashed,cyan] (0,0|-b) -- (b);
    \draw[dashed,cyan] (b|-0,0) -- (b);
    \draw[dashed,green] (0,0|-c) -- (c);
    \draw[dashed,green] (c|-0,0) -- (c);;
  %  \node[] at (-0.25,1.78){$y$};

     \node[left] at (0,0|-b) {$y_3$};
     \node[below] at (b|-0,0) {$x_3$};

     \node[left] at (0,0|-c) {$y_2$};
     \node[below] at (c|-0,0) {$x_2$};  

   \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
% draw braces
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=0.5pt,mirror},yshift=0pt] (O) -- (b) node [midway,yshift=-9pt, xshift =6pt]{$|z_3|$};
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=0.5pt},yshift=0pt] (O) -- (c) node [midway,yshift=11pt, xshift =-5pt]{$|z_2|$};

   % \node[] at (2.9,-0.25) {$x$};

    % Draw the angle
    \draw [red] (0,0.3) arc (90:33:0.3);
    \draw[red] (0,0.4)arc(90:33:0.4);
    \node[] at (60:.6)  {$\alpha$};

    % Done
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Differential Beamformer Patterns}
\end{minipage}\par\medskip
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, yes you are right, I am using the IEEE Transactions Class. Sorry if I did not include it, I did not think it was relevant, I am new to all this. Can you please clarify though, you are still using the IEEE Transactions class obviously, and still managing to center the image correct?

Comment: Using the conference class takes care of the caption, but it still forces the figure to come 'after' the text I usually have...

Comment: @TyranaSaur I don't recommend the use of the H modifier from the float package. Kind of busy right now,  but in 3 hours I can give you an alternative.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalez, also fyi, I have to use the IEEE Transactions class, no choice in that. :-/

Comment: @TyranaSaur I had some time, so I updated my answer with an option to have the figure appear exactly where you declared it. Regarding the document class, my answer uses `IEEEtran`, but with the `conference` option so your captions will be centered. Can't you use the `conference` option?

Comment: I can use the conference option, however if I include "\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}" and at the same time include "\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}" the compiler yells at me.

Comment: @TyranaSaur of course, you cannot use two `\documentclass` commands in one document; you can, however, use both options in one `\documentclass` command, as in `\documentclass[conference,journal]{IEEEtran}`

Comment: Ah! I believe this is working great now! :-) Yes, sorry about the \documentclass issue, I am very noobish on this, but learning quickly. Thanks again! :-)

Comment: Also, this works with any image right? For example, a *.png, etc right?

Comment: @TyranaSaur since you are using pdflatex, your images must be in one of three formats: `JPG`, `PNG` or `PDF`. And yes, you can do the same for any image which you want to appear exactly where you declare it in the code. If you want it to float, use `figure`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to set the figure to the current location, you can use

```
\usepackage{float}
```

With this, you can use

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  %image
\end{figure}
```

It puts the figure at the position and suppresses the floating behavoir

Comment: Ah! This appears to work nicely. It places the figure where I want it. :-) There is still the problem of the caption not being centered though... (I am using the IEEE Transactions Class, and I cannot not use it).

Comment: @TyranaSaur the issue with the caption not being centered has to do with the IEEE class you are using.  It has been answered on the site.  I think only conference class will center the caption.